# How to upgrade Java (to at least 8.0.6.25 ) in IBM DB2 v11.1

Tags: java, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to upgrade Java (to atleast 8.0.6.25 ) in IBM DB2 v11.1.

It's currently bundled but I don't know if the Java setup can separatly be upgraded in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Install your preferred JDK separately and use the following command to make db2 use it:

```
 db2 UPDATE DBM CFG USING jdk_path SDKforJava-path
```